# XStream calls are not getting called from JNI

Tags: java, xml, java-native-interface, xstream

I have a simple XStream code to serialize and de-serialize java objects. It takes a random Java Object as Object and converts it to the XML and vice-versa. It has no problems when executed as a Java program.

When I call the same function from JNI, the program exits without any error or exception. I thought sending Object as a parameter might be a problem and tried calling a dummy method with no parameter and only a print statement inside and this too did not get executed.

When I removed the references of xstream library, the dummy method started executing. I found xstream to be pretty simple to use in the place of JAXB - where I cannot pass a random objects. Is there any way to use xstream with JNI?

Answer (score 0):

My bad. In the JNI, I need to include full JAR path name. XStream I added recently in the java side and did not add the path in the JNI. I added a catch with throwable in java side which threw the exception and I understood I missed the path.

Adding Jar path in JNI solved the problem.